# Windows Server 2012 Drivers - P8Z77-M Pro

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012

I have an Asus P8Z77-M Pro motherboard, and none of the drivers on the Asus website for it work with Windows Server 2012.

Does anyone know of any drivers that would be compatible for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not to use the Asus default "setup.exe", but to use the actual driver setup.exe instead. Asus seem to have built a "this doesn't work for your OS" message into their setup file.

I've downloaded the Windows 8 x64 drivers and manually installed all, and they all work.